# What is the difference between desire and pleasure for ghusl?

Tags: salat, women, wudu, ghusl, self-purification

I am a bit embarrassed to talk about this but I need to ask: I read websites saying that ghusl is only necessary if the discharge that comes out is accompanied by pleasure and not just desire. However I have a problem: I don’t know the difference between these feelings. I read that for women the discharge also needs to be yellow and mine doesn’t seem to be yellow when aroused but I’m still unsure.
I want to ask, if i feel my private parts clench/contract at a sexual thought, does that require ghusl? I feel weird asking this but I get clenches/contractions down there quite often when aroused and I’m aroused everyday so I don’t know if I actually have to do ghusl. It’s really stressing me out. It would be quite difficult to actually have to renew my ghusl for each prayer so that’s why I’m asking.

Answer (score -1):

Asalamalikum, I would like to add my comments on this question, the difference has been taught by our beloved prophet peace be upon him, if it is just a fluid ( Pre cum) than wadu and if it is semen than gusul, the lady ask a question and if we apply that to a man than it is just erection and with the result a fluid comes out and that is not semen and it is clearly mentioned , to perform wadu for that and semen means actually discharge. Plz try to understand the difference and than give answers as per Quran and Hadees

Answer (score -2):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. I would first like to say that you never have to feel ashamed in asking question. We are all here to keep learning and keep spiritually growing. However, having modesty is a good sign but let it not stop you from learning and growing.

Below are the few scenarios which I hope will make it clear on what to do.

-----**Scenarios**-----

**Orgasm (without sex) with liquid coming out** = ghusl

**Orgasm (without sex) with no liquid coming out** = do nothing

**Sexual intercourse** = ghusl no matter if liquid comes out or not

**No orgasm and just liquid coming out due to sexual thoughts/desires** = wudu

**Quran**

> Surah #5 Verse 6: ".....And if you are in a state of janabah, then purify yourselves..."

**Hadith**

> "The Messenger of Allah was asked about prostatic fluid and he said: 'For that ablution (is necessary), and for semen, bath is necessary.'" (Ibn Majah)

> Umm Sulaim, the wife Abu Talha said, “O Allah’s Messenger! Allah is not ashamed of the truth. Is a Ghusl (bath) compulsory for a woman when she has a sexual dream?” He (ﷺ) replied, “Yes! When she sees signs of liquid” [Agreed upon]. (Bulugh al-Maram)

> "Umm Habibah bint Jahsh consulted the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and said: 'O Messenger of Allah, I suffer from Istihadah (non-menstrual vaginal bleeding).' He said: 'That is a vein, so perform Ghusl and pray.' And she used to perform Ghusl for every prayer." (An Nasai)

---

**What Can Be Done to Lessen It?**

In my opinion it would be good to get away from the causes that are creating the sexual arousal in the first place. If it is your thought that is the problem then to start engaging in positive clean thoughts. If a negative thought does arise then to start doing dhikr, removing yourself from that environment (moving away for a couple of minutes,etc.) , think of that same guy/boy as someone who only has bones and is diseased (mental imagery to cool your passion down).

Afterwards it would be good to engage in more dhikr and start fasting more frequently.

If you cannot fast then to take cold showers or supplement that can reduce your sexual desire to level that will not cause harm to the body.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.

Comment: What about the other meanings of the two most essential words? I really don't know what your peoblem is, but you hardly answer a question, but want to say your two cents on it.

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum @Sassir, i hope you are doing well. What two most essential words are you referring to? Furthermore, when you have a discourse / conversation it is beneficial for you to talk positively / kindly instead of being rude and opinionated.

Comment: This answer really doesn't make much sense with the question, sorry to say.

Comment: @LILLOFIE Hello / Salaam. Its okay if it doesn't make sense to you that much. What part(s) did you not understand. Perhaps I can make it clearer.